# What is the smallest positive integer, which can not be written without repetitions of digits and using arithmetics only?

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

> Suppose you are allowed to use all 10 digits (0,1,2,...9) at most once each; 4 arithmetic operations ($-$,$+$,$\times$,$\div$), each any number of times; parenthesises to group operations; and you can create numbers from digits by writing them together.
>   What is the smallest natural number which you would not be able to write?

For example, you can write:
$135 = 12*3*(9+6)/4$
and you can't write:
$11 = 11$
$3 = 2+3/3$
$27 = 3+4!$
$81 = 3^4$
$1 = 5/3$

Comment: @JoeZ don't forget you can "create numbers from digits writing them together" so $4817*(90+23)=544321$

Comment: What about parenthesis, or how is operator precedence handled?

Comment: @Cephalopod, you can use parenthesises. thank you.

Comment: I don't think there's any algorithm which will help solve this - it's just going to have to be bruteforce.

Comment: @Bobson well by brute force it must be more than 5000

Comment: My first bett is 987654321, slightly less than the theoretical limit of 9876543210.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, em? You just wrote this number using only digits from 1 to 9 and stringing them together.

Comment: Which is fine by the rules? For lower numbers it seems finding a counterexample will be very hard. Goldbachs conjcuture gives a strong indication, (only problem different digits) But since we still have 3 more pluses I do not see this as a problem.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar, exactly. Nobody says that this is simple. You can post partial (but correct) solution, I would be interesting to see it to. I do not understand "Goldbachs conjcuture".

Comment: "Every integer n greater than 2 can be written as the sum of two primes"

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar - But will those primes have overlapping digits?

Comment: Of course. For a number n generate the list of primes. If we find a pair with distinct digits we are good. Otherwise look for a way to make one of the primes using the remaining 3, plus symbols. If this does not work we are still not sure it is a counterexample, but it is a very likely candidate.

Comment: There an error in the given examples. 11=11 ?

Comment: @AdamSpeight, why? You can't write 1 near 1 to get 11.

Comment: @klm123 I've miss read it as can, not can't.

Answer (score 8):

Concatenation is the "most efficient" among the allowed operations, which is exmplified by this observation: If $x$ is a nonzero rational number obtained according to the rules using the $k$ digits $d_1>d_2>\ldots >d_k$, then 
$$\tag1 \max\left\{|x|,\tfrac1{|x|}\right\}\le 10^k\cdot 0.d_1d_2\ldots d_k$$
This is clear for direct concatenations and otherwise follows by induction and using $(1)$ for the summands, factors, etc.

We can strengthen this: If the last operation is $\times$ or $\div$, then 
$$\tag2\max\left\{|x|,\tfrac1{|x|}\right\}<10^k\cdot 0.85598232 $$
This follows because not both parts can use the digit $9$, hence the largest digit in on subterm is either $8$, leading to a bounding factor $0.97654321\cdot 0.87654321$; or the largest digit in one factor is $\le 7$, leading to a bounding factor $0.987654321\cdot 0.7654321$. If one takes these case distinctions a bit further, one readily finds that 
$$\tag{2'} \max\left\{|x|,\tfrac1{|x|}\right\}\le10^k\cdot 0.843973902$$
if the last operation is $\times$ or $\div$ (with the extreme given by $9642\cdot 875310$).

Moreover, if the last operation is $+$ or $-$, then 
$$\tag3|x|\le (10^{k-1}+1)\cdot 0.987654321 $$

We thus are led to believe that $987654323$ is likely not expressible: Because of two difgits $3$ it cannot be obtained from concatenation; because of $(3)$ is cannot be obtained as sum or difference; because it is prime, it cannot be obtained as product of integers (unless one factor is $1$ and we are effectively using at most $9$ digits). Remains the case that the number is obtained as a product or quotient of fractions, but at first sight this seems unplausible.

Meanwhile I brute-forced all numbers that can be obtained with only $+,-,\times$ and digit concatenation (and with all intermediate resuls $\le 10^7$). The first number that cannot be expressed this way turns out to be
$$ 8480902.$$
So unless someone manages to express $8480902$ under the original rules (i.e. with division allowed), this is the answer to the original problem.

Comment: "This follows because not both parts can use the digit 9" Why? This is in assumption that all previous operations were concatenations, but why must they?

Comment: @klm123 Each digit shall be used at most once, hence $9$ cannot occur as *used* in both parts (it may of course occur as digit in both parts, e.g. if we combine (e.g. multiply) $4+5$ and $92$, but then $9$ is *used* only in the second part). -  After the brute-force result, however, the introductory estimates have become mostly useless.

Comment: I'm missing something here. I followed you up to the brute-force consideration. How did you do that? And why are you discarding the division? Using just 0-5 digits, I have found numbers that are expressed as division (i.e. 27155=54310/2), although I cannot be certain that all of them are expressable **only** as a division.

Comment: Exhaustive searches show that for digits up to 6 and 7 the solution is unchanged by the removal of division from the permitted operations, so it's quite likely that 8480902 is the desired answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have written a Delphi application to brute force a solution. Unfortunately I see no way of solving the problem: what expression(s) results in number N? That is I see no solution other than generating all expressions and then seeing what natural numbers they result in.

So I can't really help with Bobson's crowd-sourcing approach.

I am following klm123's idea, and I have ran the application with:

**N = 3 : 0,1,2**

```
Execution time: 00:00:00
Expressions processed: 441 [Average: 27.562,5/sec]
Expressions calculated: 34 [Average: 2.125,0/sec]
Natural numbers calculated: 28 [Average: 1.750,0/sec]
Distinct natural numbers found: 14 [Average: 875,0/sec]
Highest natural found: 210
Lowest natural not found: 4
```

**N = 4 : 0,1,2,3**

```
Execution time: 00:00:00
Expressions processed: 22.924 [Average: 363.873,0/sec]
Expressions calculated: 1.464 [Average: 23.238,1/sec]
Natural numbers calculated: 871 [Average: 13.825,4/sec]
Distinct natural numbers found: 110 [Average: 1.746,0/sec]
Highest natural found: 3.210
Lowest natural not found: 25
```

**N = 5 : 0,1,2,3,4**

```
Execution time: 00:00:04
Expressions processed: 1.679.977 [Average: 401.812,2/sec]
Expressions calculated: 98.228 [Average: 23.493,9/sec]
Natural numbers calculated: 45.423 [Average: 10.864,1/sec]
Distinct natural numbers found: 884 [Average: 211,4/sec]
Highest natural found: 43.210
Lowest natural not found: 89
```

**N = 6 : 0,1,2,3,4,5**

```
Execution time: 00:08:39
Expressions processed: 159.888.346 [Average: 307.590,0/sec]
Expressions calculated: 8.867.950 [Average: 17.060,0/sec]
Natural numbers calculated: 3.236.479 [Average: 6.226,3/sec]
Distinct natural numbers found: 8.661 [Average: 16,7/sec]
Highest natural found: 543.210
Lowest natural not found: 653
```

**N = 7 : 0,1,2,3,4,5,6**

```
Execution time: 19:36:02
Expressions processed: 18.788.082.577 [Average: 266.262,5/sec]
Expressions calculated: 1.014.272.742 [Average: 14.374,2/sec]
Natural numbers calculated: 308.146.445 [Average: 4.367,0/sec]
Distinct natural numbers found: 93.219 [Average: 1,3/sec]
Highest natural found: 6.543.210
Lowest natural not found: 5.683
```

Now on to N=8. I got a few small optimizations in mind, but nothing that will cut this drastically, I presume.

### Explanation of what the application is doing

I have two input parameters: **Digits** and **Operators**. I also have some other parameters to handle output dump to disk, but they have nothing to do with the algo.

The application starts processing the empty expression: 0 length string.

Every time an expression **E** is processed, I do the following:

**1. check all Digits** - for any single digit **D** not already included in **E**, I process the expression **E**+**D** (concatenation, not sum). To optimize a bit I avoid this step if **E** ends with a closed parenthesis. I also avoid this if **D** is 0 and **E** does not end with any other Digit.

**2. check all Operators** - for any single operator **O**, I process the expression **E**+**O**. To optimize I avoid this step if **E** is empty or ends with another operator or with an open parenthesis.

**3. check ")"** - if **E** ends with a Digit or a closed parenthesis, and it has a pending unclosed parenthesis, and this contains at least one operatore, then I process the expression **E**+**)**.

**4. check "("** - if **E** is empty or ends with an Operator or an open parenthesis, then I process the expression **E**+**(**. To avoid infinite recursion there is some magic here... I do it only if the number of Digits still unused in **E** is greater the number of pending unclosed parenthesis in **E** plus 1.

**5. calculate the expression** - if **E** ends with a Digit or a closed parenthesis, and all parenthesis are balanced and are useful (contain at least one operator), and it does not start with **(** and end with **)** then I calculate the expression. If it turns out to be a natural number, then I check it with the highest found natural and lowest unfound natural.

Processing of derived expressions is obviously done through recursion. The algo seems quite efficient, apart from the parenthesis part. I have made some changes to this code and it now validates parenthesis better, avoiding some recursion in useless branches and evaluation os redundant expressions. It's not perfect, but it does cut times as N goes up. *(I am using Artem V. Parlyuk's ArtFormula package of nonvisual Delphi component for symbolic expression parsing and evaluation).*

As an aside, I also keep track of the shortest expression that can generate each natural number found. The shortest is meaningful, as it is usually the most immediate and readable. It is also always the one with no useless parenthesis ;)

### Update

Tweaking the parenthesis logic, I have stumbled upon a small bug. It was generating a lot of useless expressions (with redundant parenthesis) but it was not generating some useful expressions. With N<=5 this bug did not have any effects. With N=6 I did find 6 more natural numbers, though the lowest unfound natural is 653.

Comment: This should run faster if you only search the numbers less than the lowest one not found, in theory. That way, you can answer the question without waiting years :P

Comment: And how do you propose to "search" for a specific value? I generate expressions, and then evaluate them... using a specific library, which is actually quite fast. But if you have ideas on how to limit the generation/evaluation of expressions, please let me know. A part from that... when I say that 2908 is the lowest, I mean the application has already found expressions for all numbers up to 2907. So what I actually need is to verify if 2908 has an expression or not.

Comment: Hmm, I see what you're saying. Guess it isn't as straightforward as I thought... I'm sure there's a way to, but I'll have to think on it.

Comment: I confirm your values for the lowest natural number not found, although I think your code is quite inefficient. Mine takes 20 seconds to check N=7.

Comment: 20 secs to evaluate about one billion expressions... wow. I don't think choice of programming language or tool can make so much of a difference. Would you mind sharing the logic or the code? What are you using? How long will it take to process N=10?

Comment: I don't do any symbolic expression evaluation: I just track rational values and masks of digits which can form them. I also filter out masks which are non-optimal: e.g. I won't store the value of `5+3-2-1` because the same value can be obtained with just `5`. N=8 takes 15 minutes giving lowest natural not found of 48529; I imagine that N=9 will take a day or two, and N=10 will take a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my attempt at finding an upper bound:

We have 10 atomic values ($0..9$) and five operations ($+$, $-$, $*$, $/$, $○$; according to rules concatenation may not be used on results of other operators, let's ignore this for now)

Since all operations are binary, we need 9 operators to get a single result out of 10 values. [There are 4862 binary trees with nine nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_numbers#Applications_in_combinatorics).

There are $5^9 = 1953125$ ways to choose operators for a tree and $10! = 3628800$ ways to arrange the digit leaves.

Thus, the number must be smaller than $3628800*1953125*4862 = 34459425000000000$. Hey, this still fits into a signed 64-bit integer, so good look to the brute forcers :-)

It is possible to reduce the upper limit. The following rules were not considered by my approximation

- Concatenation may not be used on results of other operators
- $+$ and $*$ are commutative
- not all combinations result in integers
- some integers can be computed in more than one way

Comment: The maximum you can get with 9 digits and all operators are 96420*87531, so the upper bound can be much smaller: 8439739021.

Comment: You can do better than that just by stringing all the digits in descending order to make 9876543210, though.

Comment: @JoeZ. It may technically have to be an expression of some sort, meaning the upper bound would therefore be 8439739021.

Comment: @neil It depends on if "any number of times" include zero times?

Comment: @AdamSpeight That cannot be the case, or else the problem would be trivial, being able to represent all possible expression valuations from 0 to 9876543210 as a number without operations and hence everything can be represented and there is no solution.

Comment: @Neil The "any number of times" applies to operation not digits. Digits are restricted being used only once.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of crowd-sourcing the brute forcing, I've made a google spreadsheet with the list of the 4765 numbers from 1 to 9999 which can't be formed by simple concatenation.  Please pick a couple of them and work out solutions.

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oCv8zImAWJ4k-VOKRlVWQp5d58zA_C1BcJ_X7dfAwxY/edit?usp=sharing)

If we finish this set with solutions for all numbers, I'll add more.

I don't *really* expect it to be in this set, but we've got to start somewhere...

Comment: I brute-forced expressions using only digits $0,\ldots, 7$ and allowing only $+,-,\times$ and initially concatenation. Then the bound is at $48528$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen - Good to know.  I didn't *really* expect it to be solvable by hand, but it was worth the attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to approach the task solving simpler tasks with $N<9$ digits allowed.

1. N = 3: 0,1,2.
   The Answer would be $A=4$.
   Obviously, you can't reach $(N-1)N/2+1 = 4$ if you use only $-,\div,+$ operations. $\times$ operation also would help here.
   So you need to use grouping operation. But then you will get a number $R \ge 10$ and the only way to decrease it drastically to $4$ is to use division. But $10/2 = 5$ - the division is not enough too.

   It is easy to check that you can make any number $\le4$.
2. N = 4: 0,1,2,3.
   The Answer is $A=25$.
   Similarly you can't reach $7$ if you use only $-,\div,+$ operations. The maximum you can get adding $\times$ operation is (2+1)*3 = 9 (you have to multiply maximum possible numbers to reach the maximum).
   So you need to use grouping operation.
   If you group 1 and other digit, you would need to use multiplication to reach 25, but 10*2 =20 and 10*3 = 30 leaves us with 3 or 2 to finish... 12*3 = 36 and 13*2 = 26 lives us with 0... so you can do nothing here.
   If you group 2 and other digit, for example, 20 you would need to add to it something and can't reach 25 with additional 1 and 3. The same for 21,23.
   If you group 3 and other digit, like 30, you would need to subtract from it something, similarly you can't reach 25.
   If you group three digits, then you would get $R>100$ and you would need to use division, but $100/3 > 25$.

   You can check that you can make any number $\le24$.

This really looks like there is no simple pattern, the $A$ is rapidly increases with $N$, the same for number of possible ways to achieve the result.
The only patter I see is that $A < 10^{N-2}/(N-1)$, possibly this can be proven. And $10^{N-3} < A$, which is most probably will fail for big $N$.

Most probably there is no pattern for $A$ at all, and one would need to brute force it for big $N$.

Comment: It is a ridiculously difficult problem to try to take on mathematically.  Even brute forcing a solution would likely take more seconds than have passed since the universe was founded.  Don't beat yourself up.

Comment: @Neil: Can you prove that it's mathematically difficult?

Comment: @justhalf How do you expect I go about that exactly?  Divide the number of head scratches by the inverse frequency of pencil eraser usage?  I didn't say that to *prove* anything.  If you wish to demonstrate that it is, in fact easy, then I think it's safe to assume you could provide a solution, no?

Comment: I think this might be a good approach, but you'd need to do it in a base-$N$ system.  Otherwise you get gaps - there's probably no way to represent 79 using only the digits 0-3, for instance.

Comment: @Bobson, I don't understand why are you talking about 79 via 0-3 digits. May be you see more in my approach than I do? Could you explain it, please?

Comment: @klm123 - That example was off the top of my head.  Upon further investigation, I don't think base matters.  I can't figure out how to get $11_{base 3}$ from $\{0,1,2\}$.